# newcommand, $ $ and circuitikz

Tags: macros, circuitikz

I try to make a new command to avoid some typing. Don't the arguments of newcommand work within `$ $`? Or did I something else wrong?
Thanks for your help.

I get the error:

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/R=$R_{1}$,i=$I_{1}$,v=$U_{1}$' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \draw (0,0) to [\Res{1}] (3,0)
```

Here is my minimal not working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\Res}[1]{R=$R_{#1}$, i=$I_{#1}$, v=$U_{#1}$}

    \begin{circuitikz}

        \draw (0,0) to [\Res{1}] (3,0) ;

    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: often when parsing special syntax such as tikz or comma separated keys in eg `\includegraphics[width=zz, ...` tex does not expand macros, so it is not specific to `$`  it needs to "see"  the comma separated list of pgf keys directly

Comment: @ David Carlisle: does this mean, I can't use newcommand with macros like $$ at all ? Or ist there a different aproach to handle it?

Comment: as I said it is nothing to do with `$` (the normal use of `$` to enter math mode is fine inside a defined command) the tikz command needs a comma separated list of keys you could for example add the `\draw(0,0) to ` part to your definition so the macro expands first then the tikz parser starts,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can (and should) define a style:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\tikzset{
  Res/.style={R=$R_{#1}$, i=$I_{#1}$, v=$U_{#1}$},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (0,0) to [Res=1] (3,0) ;
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need the macro to expand before the tikz parser needs to see the comma separated values.

One way would be

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\Res}[2]{\draw #1 to [R=$R_{#2}$, i=$I_{#2}$, v=$U_{#2}$]}

    \begin{circuitikz}

        \Res{(0,0)}{1} (3,0) ;

    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```